# How to handle PropertyReferenceException

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have reffered to various sources but my issue still did not solve, 
Custom Repository

```
public interface BaseRepositoryCustom<ContactDTO,Long> {
    List<ContactDTO> getTestData(String name);
}
```

Impl

```
public class BaseRepositoryImpl implements BaseRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<ContactDTO> getTestData(String name) {
        List<ContactDTO> contact = entityManager.createQuery("select * from COM_CONTACT").getResultList();
        System.out.println(contact.size());
        return null;
    }
```

Main repository

```
public interface ConContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Long>,BaseRepositoryCustom {
    List<ComContact> getTestData(String name);

}
```

I will get list of DTO as my result where was my main Repository is Contact type, how can i solve this issue
Exception

```
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getTestData found for type ComContact!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:369)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:192)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Contact DTO

```
public class ContactDTO {
    private String serviceName;
    private String contactName;
    private String title;
    }
```

Contact domain model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COM_CONTACT", schema = "JMS_SCHEMA")
public class ComContact implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String serviceNm;
    private String contactNm;
    private String title;
    private long fkTemplateId;
    private Character mailFlag;
    private String mailAddress;
    private Character faxFlag;
    private String faxNr;
}
```

Comment: `ContactDTO` is not an entity but your result is returning `entity` object, so you need `Entity_To_bean` transform on result

Comment: This is very confusing. In `ConContactRepository` you use `Contact` as entity type for the JpaRepository, in `BaseRepositoryCustom` you use `ContactDTO` and as return type of your method you use `ComContact`. You should decide, which one of these types you want to use in your repository (and it should only be one of them).

Comment: In addition to the comments above, I would encourage you not to use `get` preffixed method for non-getter methods. Just name it other way around.

Comment: this is just an example where i want to try using custom method as i have difficult search queries where the result type will not  be domain object where as the return type will be like DTO, in that case I wanted to add the custom repository which will return DTO instead of domain object that is the reason i am sending DTO to ConContactRepository. Could you please help me how can i achieve it using custom repository with custom method name ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need BaseRepositoryCustom.

You said you're using Spring Data JPA.

If you annotate your ConContactRepository with @Repository.

The class ComContact doesn't have a property "name", so lets assume you want to return all ComContact objects where serviceNm equals "xxx".

In your repository, create a method called FindAllByServiceNm (String serviceNm) and it should work, no SQL needed.

If you want to get all records, try findAll and it should work.

Once you get the records you want, you may convert them into ContactDTO objects, if applicable.

Comment: Could you pleas suggest me for how can we define an custom method where i want to implement complex query.

Comment: In this case, create the method in your repository and annotate it with @Query("SELECT A from B where ....."). You don't have to implement the repository, Spring will handle it for you.

Comment: if i do not want to use @query then in that case please

Answer (score -1):

```
public interface ConContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Long>, ConContactRepositoryCustom {
  List<ContactDTO> getTestData(String name);
}

public interface ConContactRepositoryCustom {
  List<ContactDTO> getTestData(String name);
}

public class ConContactRepositoryImpl implements ConContactRepositoryCustom {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  public List<ContactDTO> getTestData(String name) {
    List<ContactDTO> contact = entityManager.createQuery("select * from COM_CONTACT").getResultList();
    System.out.println(contact.size());
    return null;
  }
}
```